# How to define a Sorted Stack by Java

Tags: java, stack, heap, priority-queue

I have a question about a stack. Generally, I will define the push method in the easiest way like

```
 Int size;
 public void push(int value){
    elements[size++] = value;}
```

If I’d like to push the integer in an increasing order and invoke pop method in a decreasing order, how could I define this method inside the same push method?

Comment: Can you explain more? My opinion is that you are writing about LIFO (last in first out) structure - that's a stack, when you put 1, 2, 3, 4 to it, you want to get 4, 3, 2, 1, so your pop is `return elements[size--];`.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have **sorting** facility in **Stack**.
 Better way is that, sort your data in ascending order before you **push** it into the stack. And while popping the data from stack, you will get data in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

The it doesnt remain a stack try [sorted list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324097/sorted-list-in-java)

and get the first element and delete it during the pop.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sorted collection to store the data instead of a plain array. You can find suggestions on creating a sorted list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416266/sorted-collection-in-java).

Answer (score -1):

A stack typically is a LIFO data structure. If you are looking for some ordered collection, look at [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html).

Comment: A SortedSet wouldn't work here as you couldn't add duplicate entries.

Comment: In sorted set the if I enter `1,2,4,4` then the set will be `1,2,4` and we loose duplicate entries.

Comment: That could be what is actually needed.